# How do users like social media information displayed?

Tags: user-behavior, icons, user-expectation

I've noticed there are three main types of *social media information*: **text**, **circle** and **square**.

**Text**

[image: Text Image]
https://www.khanacademy.org/

---

**Circle**

[image: Circle]

http://www.rollingpinbakehouse.com/

---

**Square**
[image: Square]

https://www.bankofamerica.com/

---

**Do users prefer one? Do users click on one faster?**

Comment: What's your objective? To have them share your site, connect with your entity or otherwise engage with social networks?

Comment: I want them to engage with our company's social pages. Example: Check out our Facebook page for special deals.

Comment: In that case none of the above are relevant to your problem. You need to find ways to make the link jump attractive. Be specific about deals, the destination and the content and experience they can expect upon clicking the link.

Comment: @Confused I was simply giving an example. I only want the users to interact with our social media page. What is the most appealing and click friendly way to display this?

Comment: As previous comment says, how you bait the user is going to be the most compelling part. Ask the question you want to ask, which I assume is "how do I successfully transport people to our social networking presence?"

Comment: Manipulating people is advertising. Sit down with someone in the company's advertising department, along with someone from design (the person that lays out the ads) and think about this not as an app thing, not as a web thing, but as what it is, an advertising thing.

Comment: You are correct, the question is asking on what is the best way to bait the customer to our social networking presence. Does the icon shape or appear have anything to do with this process?

Comment: Only in so far as its wrong for the context. The worst thing you can do is put people off. If it's appropriate for the context, it will work. It's the other factors that are 100's of times more important.

Comment: Would you mind posting this comment as the official answer? I make a habit of accepting all my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Confused**:

> Manipulating people is advertising. Sit down with someone in the
>   company's advertising department, along with someone from design (the
>   person that lays out the ads) and think about this not as an app
>   thing, not as a web thing, but as what it is, an advertising thing. The worst thing you can do is put people off. If it's appropriate for the context, it will work. It's the other factors that are 100's of times more important.

Note: I have posted this as a community wiki because I take no credit for this answer. all credit goes to @Confused.